# Actions or filters fired when data is saved in a custom table

Tags: plugin-development, filters, database, actions, wpdb

I'm using a plugin, and I'm trying to auto-populate a custom field (dropdown) for the subscriber form, because it should list some dynamic data (related to the websites content).

The plugin has, as far as I can see, no filters or actions for this purpose. This forces me to think in any alternative ways to deal with this.

The plugin uses custom tables (not WP native/ built-in ones), so I was thinking if there's any action or filter that is fired when data is saved in any of these custom tables.

Comment: ask the plugin author to add filters. there is no other sane way

Comment: Well, I wanted to be sure that I have no other way to solve the problem...

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, but this is not true.

Comment: @kaiser, I should have emphasized **sane** ;). You can do as your answer suggests but you still depend on the plugin author not changing the format of the data or how he uses it. If going to extreme low level manipulation you can also buffer the output and manipulate it

Comment: @MarkKaplun The OP just wants to know _if and when_ the plugin triggers any change. At this point, they can queue a later transaction where they fetch the result and add either their own modification in a second query or just do something else. I agree that it would be stupid if one would try to alter the string, but anything else is possible and not really a shaky solution as long as you know the table name.

Comment: @kaiser, ok maybe I read more in the question than there actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin probably (or: hopefully) used the `$wpdb` object, an instance of the `wpdb`-class, to add the custom table. If so (and only if so), then its author probably also uses `$wpdb->insert()` to add *rows*/ entries to the table.

Taking a look at [`wpdb::insert()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row), and looking at its [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/), you will find out that this method just is a convenience wrapper around [`wpdb::_insert_replace_helper()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_insert_replace_helper/), which sets the `$type` argument to `INSERT`. While this method *does NOT* have any filter, the source reveals that this function actually uses

```
return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $values ) );
```

While `wpdb::prepare()` does not allow any modification via filters, let's take a look at [`wpdb::query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/). There you will find the following filter:

```
$query = apply_filters( 'query', $query );
```

Now that we have an *entry point*, where we can add modifications, let's talk about how to *identify* the custom table that is filled with data. Looking at the SQL statement that gets shoveled into the statement for execution, you will notice the following line:

```
$sql = "$type INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($formats)";
```

The `$table` variable comes from the function definition, which is the first argument of the `$wpdb->insert()` call. Normally any sane developer would use `"{$wpdb->prefix}custom_table_name"` there, to avoid a broken plugin if the table prefixed was changed away from `wp_` inside `wp-config.php`.

Finally:

```
<?
/* Plugin Name: Do something when a custom table gets data added or altered */
add_filter( 'query', function( $query ) {
    // Return SQL unmodified. Not the table we are targeting.
    if ( false === strstr( $query, "{$wpdb->prefix}custom_table_name" ) ) {
        return $query;
    }

    // Return SQL unmodified. Not the actions we are targeting.
    # @TODO If you only want to act on either of them, modify the if-clause
    if ( 
        false === strstr( $query, "INSERT" ) 
        AND false === strstr( $query, "REPLACE" )
    ) {
        return $query;
    }

    # @TODO Do your custom task here and…
    # …modify according the query to your likings.

    return $query;
} );
```

Keep in mind that this plugin runs on *each single query* now. You might want to add checks like `is_admin()` and wrap the whole block of code in a function that is attached to a more exclusive hook to reduce the number of executions for it. Else you might slow down your site significantly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Kaiser and @MarkKaplun. This is what I love about WP, there is always a way through which a solution can be worked out!

Comment: Excellent answer... A  remaining question, though, is whether it would not be easier just to fork the plugin. That's often the case, esp if the developer is unresponsive to reasonable feature requests.

Comment: Holy shit! @kaiser flirts with demons!!! This answer is cold and hard. I agree with CKMacLeod fork the plugin at this point. Kick ass solution tho kaiser.